# Nuxtjs SEO implention with v-html

Tags: nuxt.js

The generated code is:

```html
<p>Diwali</p>
```

but I only want `Diwali` to be printed.
How could I do that?

Second part of my question:
Also the question is that SEO take lot of time for it's implementation. It should be Diwali only how I do it?

```html
<ShareNetwork
  v-for="network in networks"
  :network="network.network"
  :key="network.network"
  :style="{backgroundColor: network.color}"
  :url="sharing.url"
  :title="title"
  :description="description"
  :quote="sharing.quote"
  :hashtags="sharing.hashtags"
  :twitterUser="sharing.twitterUser"
>
  <i :class="network.icon"></i>
  <span>{{ network.name }}</span> 
</ShareNetwork>
```

I am using the [vue-social-sharing](https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing) package.

Comment: Welcome! Please be more precise of what is happening here. Where is `ShareNetwork` coming from? A specific package? Please link it too (update your question). Then, what is the desired result that you're expecting? `Diwali`? Isn't it what you already have here?

Comment: yes actaually it gonna printed <p>Diwali</p> it should be only Diwali.......i have to print ..when i started posting my post on twitter then it printed like<p>Diwali</p>...it is title of that post...and (diwali here is nothing more than the dyamic data associate with it

Comment: I've edited your question, tell me if it is correct, sorry if it's not. Also, I did not get the second part of your question. Can you explain it a bit better? And, what is the package you're using here? Or is it a custom component? Are you using Nuxt's SEO capabilities? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/meta-tags-seo

Comment: yes u get exactly what i mean for the first part,,,,i  am using vue-social-share plugin along with nuxt meta tags but it doesnt work properly...can u help me out?

Comment: What is your version of the `vue-social-sharing` package? (in `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`) Also, what is the issue for the `p` tags? Why are they bothering you so much? It looks like the package cannot just render the text but you can totally work around this tag afterwards with some CSS.